# Vertical-align + Vertical Linear-gradient bug in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, vertical-alignment, linear-gradients

I just encountered a bug in Internet Explorer 11, that (of course) doesn't occur in the other browsers.

I have:

- a button-styled `<a>`
- with a vertical linear-gradient applied
- and a vertical-align CSS styling
- in a `<ul>` list (not needed, but the reason why I set a vertical alignment)

... and, as you can see in the below snippet, the top color repeats at the bottom of the button!

(I added pretty colors to better visualize the issue)

Any idea where it comes from and how to deal with this?
Thanks.

```css
body {
 background: hsl(0,100%,50%);
}
li {
 height:50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.btn {
    background: hsl(100, 100%, 50%);
    border: outset 1px grey;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px;
}
.vertgradient {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, hsl(200, 100%, 50%) 0%, hsl(50,100%,70%) 100%);
}
.vertalign {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.horizgradient {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, hsl(200, 100%, 50%) 0%, hsl(50,100%,70%) 100%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="btn vertgradient vertalign">On IE 11, yellow line at the bottom</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="btn horizgradient vertalign">No problem with a horizontal gradient</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="btn vertgradient">No problem without "vertical-align"</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="btn vertalign">No problem without "linear-gradient"</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a displaying issue, concerning the use of `inline` elements, as `block` or `inlne-clock` elements, in this case an `a` (`inline` by default) used as an `inline-clock` element without a proper definition. All other browsers present the same bug, but the final rendering presents no visible issues.

To solve the problem, just add `display: inline-block;` to the buttons (`a.btn`).

```css
body {
    background: hsl(0,100%,50%);
}
li {
    height:50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    background: hsl(100, 100%, 50%);
    border: outset 1px grey;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px;
}
.vertgradient {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, hsl(200, 100%, 50%) 0%, hsl(50,100%,70%) 100%);
}
.vertalign {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.horizgradient {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, hsl(200, 100%, 50%) 0%, hsl(50,100%,70%) 100%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="btn vertgradient vertalign">On IE 11, yellow line at the bottom</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="btn horizgradient vertalign">No problem with a horizontal gradient</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="btn vertgradient">No problem without "vertical-align"</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="btn vertalign">No problem without "linear-gradient"</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```